# How to get element id based on class name properly?

Tags: javascript, jinja2

I am trying to get the `id` which is dynamically generated. I am using a class name to access it. If I click on the `td` item once, there is no alert. But when I click twice I will get the alert (for the first time). If I click on the second item, I get an alert two times. If on third, I get it three times and so on. What is the error?

My JavaScript code:

```
function myFunction() {
    $('.task0').click(function() {
   var x = $(this).data('id');
    alert(x);
});
}
```

My HTML-Flask code:

```
   <tbody>
   {% set ns = namespace(num=1) %}
   {% for task in tasklist %}
   <tr>
      <td>{{ ns.num }}</td>
      <td class="task0" data-id="{{ task[0] }}"><a href="javascript:myFunction();" >{{ task[0] }}</a></td>
      {% for i in range(1,task|count) %}
      <td>{{ task[i] }}</td>
      {% endfor %}
   </tr>
   {% set ns.num = ns.num+1 %}
   {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function twice. The `.click` you are using in jquery is already calls the function then your make the `a` tag call the JavaScript function as well. Remove the call to the function from the a tag

Comment: I tried..its not working : $('.task0').click(function() {
        var x = $(this).data('id');
        alert(x);
    });

replaced href with # in a tag

Comment: Where did you write this please

Comment: inside <script> tag

Comment: <script>
$(document).on('click', '.task0',function() {
   var x = $(this).data('id');
    alert(x);
});
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Every time you click on td you attach one more listener. you need to attach listner at once for all dynamically created elements.

remove javascript function call in your html part.
and change your javascript  as below.

```
$(document).on(click, '.tasklink', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var x = $(this).parents('td.task0').data('id');
    alert(x);
})


 <tbody>
       {% set ns = namespace(num=1) %}
       {% for task in tasklist %}
       <tr>
          <td>{{ ns.num }}</td>
          <td class="task0" data-id="{{ task[0] }}"><a class="tasklink" href="#" >{{ task[0] }}</a></td>
          {% for i in range(1,task|count) %}
          <td>{{ task[i] }}</td>
          {% endfor %}
       </tr>
       {% set ns.num = ns.num+1 %}
       {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
```

Comment: but this is reloading my page

Comment: reloading because href is present in a tag. add a class to a tag and add a listener to prevent reloading. will update code as well

Comment: ok so when you click on a link it just dont allow click on td to execute because of event.preventDefault() . i updated code again with attaching listener to a tag instead of td.